# Having trouble with Onclick event in JS

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have the following code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/096da5805e39434b707c6fbd970ccbff.
Now when I open up the calc.html in my browser and type two numbers (5,6) in the spaces and click on submit nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the shortest possible code to reproduce your issue in your question itself. Thanks!

Comment: You're doing the variable definitions wrong. Do `var a = ...`, not `... = a`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
document.getElementById(var1) = a;
document.getElementById(var2) = b;
```

To:

```
Var a = document.getElementById("var1");
Var b = document.getElementById("var2");
```

The reason for this is because you need to declare your variables first.

As well;  by not using quotation marks the javascript is looking within the script tag for a variable by the name of var1 (and var 2 respectively.)

By using quotations it understands that the scope is the whole html document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `onClick` to `onclick` and `document.getElementById("var1").value = a` to `var a= document.getElementById("var1").value`. for var b also and close the id with quotes `"var1"` .Try this it will help you :)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>V CALC</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sum() {
      var a = document.getElementById("var1").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("var2").value;
      var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
      document.write(c);
    }
  </script>
  <p>Type first number:</p>
  <input type="text" id="var1"></input>
  <p>Type second number:</p>
  <input type="text" id="var2"></input>
  <br />
  <p>Result</p>
  <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="sum();"></input>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ill defo give it a shot and then tell you whetherit worked! Thanks so much tho!

Comment: So it worked! One last problem: When I submit the values for computation the calculator spits a wrong answer at me. Whats going on??? The calculator is available heere: https://cdvcalc.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>V CALC</title>
</head>
<html>
<head>
<title>V CALC</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Type first number:</p>
<input type="text" id="var1">
<p>Type second number:</p>
<input type="text" id="var2">
<br />
<p>Result</p>
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onClick="sum();"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function sum(){
    var a=parseInt(document.getElementById('var1').value);
    var b=parseInt(document.getElementById('var2').value); 
    var c = a + b;
    document.write(c);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the parseInt to convert the string number in a number and assigned a var a as it seen.